# Setting an object on req. in the first of two middlwares seems to not be present at the time the second middlware is called

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two express middlwares where one is setting an object to the req and the other that follows it uses that object to turn a switch statement.

Here's an illustration:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).end()
  }
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
  return jwt.verify(token, config.database.jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) { return res.status(401).end() }

    const userId = decoded.sub
    return User.findById(userId, (userErr, user) => {
      if (userErr || !user) {
        return res.status(401).end()
      }
      req.user = {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name
      }
      return next()
    })
  })
}

    //My route
        userpage.get('/', authCheck, (req, res) => {
          return Event.findOne()
          .populate('attending.user', 'name') 
          .exec((err, newEvent) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
              res.status(400).end()
            }
            let uids = []
            let imAttending = false
            newDinner.attending.user.map(obj => {
              uids.push(obj._id)
              })
            console.log(uids) // Shows the array with all uids
            // Double checked that it is indeed an array
            let isArr = Object.prototype.toString.call(uids) === '[object Array]'
            console.log(isArr) // true
            console.log(req.user._id) // Shows the id and it's indeed matching one of the ids in the uids array
            imAttending = uids.indexOf(req.user._id) > -1
            console.log(imAttending)  // false <--- Should be true
            // Test
            let id = '57ec2203ba3e994c7c9d5832' // I litraly copy pasted that from the console.log(req.user._id)
            imAttendingII = uids.indexOf(id) > -1
            console.log(imAttendingII) // true ???? what the heck?
            // checking it's the same type as suggested in one of the comments
            let check = ['57ec2203ba3e994c7c9d5832'].indexOf(req.user._id) === -1
            console.log(check) //true
          })
        })
```

The comments below reassured me that it's not an async issue and following the results I'm getting I'm lost at what it could be.

Edit:
The following works though, and shows true. But checking on the _id felds doesn't work even after doing `uids.indexOf(req.user._id.toString()) > -1` on the _id element:

```
newEvent.attending.user.map(obj => {
      names.push(obj.name)
    })
    imAttending = names.indexOf(req.user.name) > -1 // imAttending = true
```

Comment: It looks like you want to call next() in the first middleware from a resolved Promise

Comment: The middleware won't hand off to the next middleware until the next function is called. Since you are only calling it in the callback to the async function it should already be waiting for req.user to be set before moving on to the next handler.

Comment: Your code you show right now will only call `next()` after completing the DB round trip and setting the `req.user` property.  See my answer below, it may be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: That's also what I was thinking but if you follow my edit I just couldn't explain the results illustrated there in any other way but an async thing.

Comment: @S.Schenk Are you sure that req.user._id and the elements of the uids are of the same type? For instance: ['12345'].indexOf(12345) === -1. Have you tried to cast req.user._id to string before performing the indexOf? uids.indexOf('' + req.user._id) ?

Comment: yeah it returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to add another answer because of the additional information provided in the question.

It looks like you're using MongoDB and Mongoose (which should be in the tags if I'm right).  Given that, a user document's `_id` property will *not* be equal to the string form of it, because the representation is actually `ObjectID('blahblahblah')`, it's not actually a string under the hood.  If you `console.log()` it, it will look like a string because console.log calls toString() under its hood.

So the evaluation you might want to try is:

```
imAttending = uids.indexOf(req.user._id.toString()) > -1;
console.log(imAttending); // should be true
```

As a side note, this is also why it's a great reason to use something like `node-inspector` to set breakpoints and step through your code, rather than relying on console statements to debug.  You'll see the actual representation of the various bits, rather than their stringified form.

Comment: I've tried it and it's still false which is extremely odd because when I've switched to check the match on the name, which is the other parameter I'm setting to the req.user object, it works just fine. Maybe I need to turn the list of id's I'm adding into the uids array into strings as well? Oh and yes I'm using mongoose, I'll add that to the tags.

Comment: I feel like the issue might actually lie within the `uid` var, when mapping through `newDinner`, mongo *might* have saved the `_id` as it's own unique ID. So maybe casting it with `toString()` would help resolve it?

Comment: Well, either way @S.Schenk you need to inspect the values you're comparing at the point of comparison (including type checking) to know what's going on and why they're not equal.  e.g. my recommendation of using node-inspector.

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined using npm-inspector so for now I'm using: let check = typeof(req.body._id) === 'string'

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of toString() all along. The results you get back from querying the db are not necessarily the type you think it might be.